# PHP redirect with inserting constant suffix inside the url

Tags: php, url, redirect, opencart

I have a page with the following url-type:

> https://domain.name/brandname

I need it to be 303-redirected to

> https://domain.name/constant-category-name/brand_brandname

where the part of a url

> constant-category-name/brand_

should be inserted in the url right after the https://domain.name/

filetype= .twig , Opencart 3

Answer (score 1):

Something like this :

```
<?php

$url = "https://domain.name/brandname";
preg_match('/\/(?:.(?!\/))+$/', $url,$matches);
$brandname = ltrim ($matches[0], "/");
$newurl =  "https://domain.name/constant-category-name/brand_".$brandname;
header('Location: '.$newurl);
```

Comment: It works, but the "brandname" in url is a variable. I have few brands. I need function to read the current url of a page and insert "constant-category-name/brand_" after the root of same domain of course, but before various brandnames. So result would be some like: https://domain.name/brandname1 >redirects to> https://domain.name/constant-category-name/brand_brandname1, https://domain.name/brandname2 >redirects to> https://domain.name/constant-category-name/brand_brandname2 ... and so on

Comment: That’s exactly what the code do !

Comment: Change var $url by $url= (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}";

Comment: In a other hand, you can use .htaccess with regex redirection if your server http is apache ! Check this : https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215747748-How-can-I-redirect-and-rewrite-my-URLs-with-an-htaccess-file-

Comment: I added the line "var $url by $url=..." and 500 error appeared. Tnx for the .htaccess reference, I'll try